# How can I get Zend_Db to select one column only from a large query?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a fairly complex query in SQL that performs a count across two tables. The query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(pages.id)) AS `count` 
    FROM `pages` 
    INNER JOIN `pageRegions` ON pageRegions.pageId = pages.id 
    WHERE (MATCH (pages.name, pageRegions.contents) AGAINST ('+keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + 
(SELECT COUNT(documents.id) AS `count` 
    FROM `documents` 
    INNER JOIN `files` ON files.id = documents.file 
    WHERE (MATCH (documents.name, 
              files.name, 
              files.extracted_text) AGAINST ('+keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) AS count
```

Unfortunately when I have the following code using Zend_Db the query includes a load of additional columns so the addition of both queries obviously fails:

```
$total_count_select = $PagesTable->getAdapter()
    ->query('((' . $pages_total_count_select . ') + 
              (' . $legal_resources_total_count_select . ')
             ) AS count');
```

Where `$pages_total_count_select` and `$legal_resources_total_count_select` are both `Zend_Db_Select` objects.

I have tried using the `columns()` method to specify the columns I want on each select object like so:

```
$legal_resources_total_count_select->columns('COUNT(documents.id) AS count');
```

But this just appears to append onto the select query rather than only returning the column specified.

So the Zend generated query ends up looking like this:

```
SELECT ((SELECT `pages`.*, 
                 ((1.3 * (MATCH(pages.name) AGAINST ('+keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + 
                       (0.8 * (MATCH(pageRegions.contents) AGAINST ('+keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) AS `score`, 
                     `pages`.`name` AS `page_name`, 
                     `pages`.`id` AS `page_id`, 
                     `pageRegions`.*, 
                     COUNT(DISTINCT(pages.id)) AS `count`
         FROM `pages`
         INNER JOIN `pageRegions` ON pageRegions.pageId = pages.id
         WHERE (MATCH (pages.name, pageRegions.contents) AGAINST ('+keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
         ORDER BY `score` DESC)

            + 

          (SELECT `documents`.*,
                   ((1.3 * (MATCH(documents.title) AGAINST ('+keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + 
                       (0.8 * (MATCH(documents.short_description, files.NAME, files.extracted_text) AGAINST ('+keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) AS `score`,
                     `files`.*, 
                    COUNT(documents.id) AS `count`
         FROM `documents`
         INNER JOIN `files` ON files.id = documents.file
         WHERE (MATCH (documents.title, documents.short_description, files.name, files.extracted_text) AGAINST ('+keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
         ORDER BY `score` DESC)
        ) AS COUNT
```

How can I get rid of all the extra columns it is selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one part of your code, where you construct the `$pages_total_count_select` and `$legal_resources_total_count_select`.

You missed one parameter in the way to build these, which is the array of columns you want, if you do not give it it takes table.*.

So just check the way you create the select and add one argument with an empty array.

**UPDATE:**
So you do:

```
$select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
```

Just after that redo a `->from()` call with your Zend_Db_Table ($this here) here you can specify the columns, so an empty array or the only one you want:

```
$select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
$select->from($this, array(new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(documents.id) AS count')));
```

Comment: The `$select` is generated in a method in an instance of a class that extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` like so `$select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);`. Looking at the Zend source code I don't see any parameter that accepts an array there.

Comment: @Treffynnon : see my update, for select coming from a Zend_Db_Table the column override is only in from(), not columns()